# Idiomatic approach to allowing returning all attributes when method signature includes an explicit return_attrs arg

Tags: python, keyword-argument, optional-arguments

I am building a Python wrapper for a SOAP API.  The SOAP schema defines methods with the following common signature for `list` methods:

`ListObjectReq(searchCriteria, returnedTags)`

The API requires the client **explicitly** define **all** attributes for an endpoint to be returned.  This is a pain and is burdensome for the user.  I would like to wrap this with an option to return all attributes for a given method call if desired.

My question is, what is the most pythonic way to do this?  Would I simply allow:

1. Pass the `str` `"all"`:

   object.list(search_criteria=search_criteria,  returned_tags="all")
2. Pass the `all` function:

   object.list(search_criteria=search_criteria, returned_tags=all)
3. Make `returned_tags` a `kwarg`, and add an additional `kwarg` option `return_all`.

   object.list(search_criteria=search_criteria, return_all=True)

   If so, what is the best approach for internally handling cases when both are supplied?

   - Simply ignore `returned_tags` if `return_all` is supplied?
   - Raise an error `returned_tags` are provided and  `return_all=True`?

I'm probably boiling the ocean, but am just looking for the sanest approaching to deal with these types of situations.

Comment: This is highly subjective, but my inclination would be to make the *lack of* the `returned_tags` argument be the trigger for returning all the attributes.  Treating `"all"` as a special tag name has a potential problem: what happens when you run across an object that actually has an attribute named "all"?

Comment: Understood.  What you're saying actually makes the most sense to me.  Probably what I'd go with.  Is there a better way to frame this question to avoid the subjectivity?  I presume not, but what I'd ideally be looking for would be some sort of PEP reference which recommends what to do in these types of situations.

Comment: My only reticence is that pulling "all" is expensive, which is why I was mulling over some sort of a tag to avoid making it the default behaviour.  Again, subjective.